# Parse specific item in XML by id

Tags: python, xml, rss

I'm a beginner so to improve myself i'm working on those kind of things.

I'm trying to get a specific rss/xml item with it's id.

Live [XML/RSS example is here](https://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/feed/)

I want to get specific blog post content by using "post-id" how do can I do it?

sorry if this is a common question but i really can't find a real solution for this one.

my code is this;

```
import discord
import requests
import feedparser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

blog_url = "https://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/feed/"
upd_url = "https://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/category/updates/feed/"
history_file = "history.txt"
h_file = open("history.txt", "a")


def scrap_rss(scrap_param):
    article_list = []
    try:
        r = requests.get(scrap_param)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, features='xml')
        articles = soup.findAll('item')
        postids = soup.findAll('post-id')
        print('The scraping job succeeded: ', r.status_code)
        for a in articles:
            title = a.find('title').text
            link = a.find('link').text
            published = a.find('pubDate').text
            postid = a.find('post-id').text
            article = {
                'title': title,
                'link': link,
                'published': published,
                'post-id': postid
                }
            article_list.append(article)
            with open(history_file) as f:
                if postid in f.read():
                    print("true")
                else:
                    print("false"+ postid)
                    h_file.write(postid+"\n")
                    #newpost = a.find(".//item/[post-id="+postid+"]/name")
        #newpost = postids.find(text="29701")

        return print(article_list)
    except Exception as e:
        print('The scraping job failed. See exception: ')
        print(e)
print('Starting scraping')
scrap_rss(blog_url)
print('Finished scraping')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is looking for an item with a given post-id (31917) and extract the pubDate

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

r = requests.get('https://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/feed/')
if r.status_code == 200:
    root = ET.fromstring(r.text)
    item = [item for item in root.findall('.//item') if
            item.find('{com-wordpress:feed-additions:1}post-id').text == '31917'][0]
    print(f'published at {item.find("pubDate").text}')
```

output

```
published at Thu, 03 Dec 2020 22:13:08 +0000
```